# Git: make text files as binary while still showing a text diff

Tags: git

I have some special files in my repo that although they are text files they are marked as binary in `.gitattributes` so they don't get automatically merged if we have a conflict: I need to choose between one version of the file or another. (*)

However it still would be useful to show the text diff of those files in order to make a decision or to see the changes between different commits. 
I can do that using an external diff tool, and github actually shows the text diff, but I wonder if I can configure git so its internal diff tool work that way.

(*) We are working with Unity3D and storing its internal data files as text (prefabs, scenes, etc) so they are compressed efficiently in the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`binary` is a macro that disables diffing, line ending normalization, and merging. You seem to really only need the latter. For that, try using `-merge` instead. If you want to disable line ending normalization, too, use `-merge -text`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need: prevent merge but not the diff. Thanks, missed that option in the .gitattributes manpage

Answer (score 0):

You could define a special diff filter for these files.

To achieve this you would add the following configuration to your `.gitconfig` file: (The name `binary-text` is arbitrary)

```
[diff "binary-text"]
     textconv = cat
```

`textconv` defines the tool to convert the binary files to usual text, since your files are usual text files a simple `cat` should be sufficient. To enable diffing you have to specifiy the diff filter for the file types.

So lets say the files end on `.foo`.

Now add the following to your `.gitattribute` file:

```
*.foo diff=binary-text
```

Now diff should work as expected.

For more information on this you can read the [Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) chapter from the Pro Git book.

Comment: Using a custom diff would not prevent the merging of the binary-text files. The -merge option is the one I need, but thanks